# Do we have a freezer charm for Queen Version of Openstack

Tags: lubuntu, juju, maas

Do we have a freezer charm for Queen Version Openstack.We are planning to deploy queen and looking for freezer charm but unable to find it .Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenStack Charms project does not have a charm for Freezer and Ubuntu does not published packages - so there are both packaging and charming development required to support this project.

If you'd like to have a go at writing a charm for Freezer take a read through the [charm development guide](https://docs.openstack.org/charm-guide/latest/new-api-charm.html).